# Передача объекта при создании потока и вызов метода sleep

Tags: java

```
public class SynTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();
        Thread t = new Thread(t1);
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Что даёт передача экземпляра класса (`t1`) как аргумента в поток?

Почему мы используем класс-обертку (наверное) `Thread` для `.sleep`?
Не нужно ли использовать имя переменной потока, который уже стартовал, т.е. `t.sleep(5)`? Или это ошибка у автора кода?

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        a("Thread1");
    }

    synchronized void a(String s)  {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(s + " метод а");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конструктор `Thread` передаётся объект, реализующий интерфейс `Runnable`. Когда поток запускается, вызывается метод `run` у переданного объекта. Наличие у объекта метода `run` гарантируется как раз имплементацией интерфейса `Runnable`.

Метод `Thread.sleep` заставляет текущий (в котором вызван данный метод) поток приостановить своё выполнение на заданное время. Нестатического метода `sleep` в классе `Thread` вообще нет.

Answer (score 1):

Поток в поток не передается, а передается `Runnable` в поток. Это стандартный способ запустить кусок кода в новом потоке, не наследуясь от класса потока. В частности, это нужно, чтобы использовать пулы потоков.

`Thread.sleep(long ms)` -- статический метод, который останавливает текущий поток на `ms` миллисекунд. Для того, чтобы дождаться окончания потока `t`, можно использовать `t.join()`.

Comment: А если допустим мы запустили 20 потоков, а потом

Comment: Thread.sleep, какой из них остановится?

Comment: Остановится именно текущий, то есть тот, в котором была вызвана функция `sleep`.